# Rewritable T-shirt?

Tags: clothing

They just started dress down Friday at the office.

I would like to wear a T-shirt every week, with a slogan of my own devising.

I *could* print an iron-on, but the cost would a lot, as I want a new slogan every week.

(Where) can I buy some felt pens which will wash out, or, preferably, iron-on which I can print and wash off?

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to find the right felt pens in the childrens toys section in your nearest store.
To save the sanity of creative toddlers' moms, many manufacturers have launched felt pens that can be washed out of fabrics and other materials, whether the drawing was put there intentionally or not.

A random example (no endorsement whatsoever) would be the [Crayola washable markers](http://shop.crayola.com/color-and-draw/markers/ultra-clean-markers-broad-line-classic-colors-10-ct.-5878510001.html) - available in many colour combinations and tip versions. Other manufacturers will probably have similar products.

Answer (score 1):

You could and should use Crayola markers for these because, being made for kids, Crayola wanted parents to easily get rid of messes. If not Crayola, any children's markers would work. I suggest the ones that say washable or advertise that they are washable, before writing all over our shirt make sure the marker you are using will wash out of the fabric you choose to use.